# Expected Number of Loops from Nesting Closed Function

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a finite set, $S$, and a one-to-one function such that $f:S\to S$. We define a loop as an instance of $f(...f(a)...)=a$ for some $k$ iterations of nesting the function within itself. We know that for each set, at least $1$ loop must exist, and that no loops intersect since it's a one-to-one function. My question is, how many loops can we expect if the size of $S$ is $n$ (i.e. try to find the explicit form of $L(n)$)? What I know so far is that $L(1)=1$ and probably $\lim_{n\to\infty}L(n)=\infty$. Also, I wrote a little simulation that tested $n$ from $1$ to $100$ for $10,000$ trials each and it appears the relationship is somewhat logarithmic. The results are below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
1: 1.0
2: 1.5045
3: 1.8184
4: 2.0929
5: 2.2747
6: 2.4513
7: 2.5833
8: 2.721
9: 2.8445
10: 2.9137
11: 3.0369
12: 3.0975
13: 3.1871
14: 3.2604
15: 3.3159
16: 3.389
17: 3.4196
18: 3.4808
19: 3.5732
20: 3.5994
21: 3.6848
22: 3.7041
23: 3.7628
24: 3.7794
25: 3.8164
26: 3.867
27: 3.8887
28: 3.93
29: 3.9738
30: 4.0105
31: 4.0483
32: 4.0503
33: 4.077
34: 4.1253
35: 4.1476
36: 4.1869
37: 4.1906
38: 4.2298
39: 4.2324
40: 4.267
41: 4.3302
42: 4.3197
43: 4.3616
44: 4.4119
45: 4.3936
46: 4.3861
47: 4.4259
48: 4.4645
49: 4.4597
50: 4.4999
51: 4.513
52: 4.5477
53: 4.5665
54: 4.5713
55: 4.5841
56: 4.6307
57: 4.6295
58: 4.6588
59: 4.7008
60: 4.6451
61: 4.7015
62: 4.6883
63: 4.7326
64: 4.7167
65: 4.7513
66: 4.7705
67: 4.7709
68: 4.7904
69: 4.8286
70: 4.8387
71: 4.8824
72: 4.846
73: 4.8466
74: 4.8527
75: 4.9124
76: 4.9098
77: 4.8895
78: 4.9421
79: 4.9558
80: 4.9605
81: 4.9909
82: 4.9901
83: 5.0157
84: 5.0223
85: 5.03
86: 5.0407
87: 5.0841
88: 5.0697
89: 5.062
90: 5.0585
91: 5.1167
92: 5.0829
93: 5.1316
94: 5.1422
95: 5.1148
96: 5.1581
97: 5.1524
98: 5.1512
99: 5.1728
100: 5.2072
```

Comment: What is $L(n)$?

Comment: So we have $S_n \to S_n$. And we want to determine average number of elements in loop (cycle)?

Comment: @Gae.S. $L(n)$ is the expected number of loops given a set of size $n$. The table I provided shows the mapping of $n$ to $L(n)$. I'm trying to find an explicit form of $L(n)$.

Comment: @openspace We can do that too. I'm looking for $L(n)$, but the average number of elements in a cycle can be expressed as $n/L(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason $L(n)$ appears to logarithmic is because
$$
L(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$
for all positive integers $n$.

**Explanation:**

For each positive integer $n$, let $L(n)$ be the expected number of cycles (including singleton cycles) for a random element of $S_n$.

For convenience, we set $L(0)=0$.

For a random element of $S_n$, the length of the cycle which contains $1$ is one of the values $1,...,n$, with all $n$ values equally likely.

Thus for each $k\in\{0,...,n-1\}$, the case where there are exactly $k$ elements of $\{2,...,n\}$ which are not in the cycle containing $1$ contributes
$$
{\small{\frac{1}{n}}}{\,\cdot\,}(1+L(k))
$$
 to the expected number of cycles.

If follows that for all positive integers $n$ we have
$$
L(n)
=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left({\small{\frac{1}{n}}}{\,\cdot\,}(1+L(k))\right)
=
1+{\small{\frac{1}{n}}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} L(k)
$$
Then we get
\begin{align*}
L(n+1)
&=
1+{\small{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\sum_{k=0}^n L(k)
\\[4pt]
&=
1+{\small{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\left(L(n)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} L(k)\right)
\\[4pt]
&=
1+{\small{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\Bigl(L(n)+\bigl(n(L(n)-1)\bigl)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
1+{\small{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\Bigl((n+1)L(n)-n)\bigl)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
L(n)+\frac{1}{n+1}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, noting that $L(1)=1$, it follows that
$$
L(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;
$$
for all positive integers $n$, as claimed.

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty cool! How did you derive it?

Comment: I'll edit in an explanation . . .